# How to build bundle-stats.json in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I need to build bundle-stats.json to work with webpack-bundle-analyzer. 
Here how i'm trying build it , but it does not creating any file.

```
npm run build -- --stats
```

Could you please help me

Answer (score 14):

The `--stats` flag was added back into CRA in [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8790).

So you can use `webpack-bundle-analyzer` again.

Comment: Although I could see [the line in build script](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/build.js#L55) I could not get this to work with `create-react-app: 5.0.0`

Answer (score 8):

`stats` have been remove from `CRA` [see](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/140e182e7d7fbeb8d507b6be4813a4ce0bf9b6d8#diff-8d717038a105d8c7993616152faa1a38)

It's recommended to use `source-map-explorer`

```
npm i -g source-map-explorer
source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'.
```

Comment: Thanks for advice ! what does percentage mean in source-map-explorer?

Comment: it represente how much space it take in the bundled file

Comment: Is there a way to generate stats.json?

Comment: take a look at the [options](https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer/blob/master/README.md#Options), you can add the following `--json stats.json`

Comment: It's back again https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/build.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `@craco/craco` which is a tool to use a custom webpack configuration with Create React App.

As explained on [this article](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-analyze-and-improve-your-create-react-app-production-build-4f34):

1. Install `@craco/craco` and `webpack-bundle-analyzer`

   ```
   npm install @craco/craco webpack-bundle-analyzer --save-dev
   ```
2. Create a file named `craco.config.js` in the *root* of your project folder with this content:

   ```
   const BundleAnalyzerPlugin =
     require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

   module.exports = function () {
     return {
       webpack: {
         plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: "server" })],
       },
     };
   };
   ```
3. Add this "analyze" script to your `package.json` scripts sections:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "start": "react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject",
   +   "analyze": "craco build"
     }
   }
   ```
4. Now run:

   ```
   npm run analyze
   ```

Because you set the analyzerMode to "server" in your `craco` config, you will automatically get your browser open with the results served as a webpage (you can use the "json" option if you want the output without involving the browser)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add the webpack-bundle-analyzer to your dev dependecies:

```
yarn add -D webpack-bundle-analyzer
```

Then you can sequentially run commands:

```
yarn build -- --stats

yarn webpack-bundle-analyzer ./build/bundle-stats.json
```

Or, for your convenience, you can add the script to your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "analyze": "yarn build -- --stats && yarn webpack-bundle-analyzer ./build/bundle-stats.json"
}
```

Instead of yarn you can use npm, just edit the command accordingly.

Then you can run the script using `yarn analyze` or the scripts runner UI available in VS Code like I do. You can also add a script for deleting the build folder if this already exists before creating a new one. For this, dependently on your platform, you can use the cmd or bash command:

- cmd: `if exist build\\ ( rmdir /s /q .\\build )`
- bash: `[ -d 'build' ] && rm -r build`

So the final solution will look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "analyze": "yarn remove_build && yarn build -- --stats && yarn webpack-bundle-analyzer ./build/bundle-stats.json",
  "remove_build": "if exist build\\ ( rmdir /s /q .\\build )"
}
```